# Como passar uma dependência Angular Js e Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Eu estou tentando passar uma dependência no meu module pra usar um filtro o unique, preciso filtrar nomes nas minhas `Views`. O que acontece é o seguinte: quando eu faço dessa forma, no meu controller, sem criar rotas no meu sistema, da certo.

```
angular.module("myApp,['ui.filters']")
       .controller("papaRoca",function($scope,Data, $location).
```

Vocês podem ver que eu coloquei a dependência `['ui.filters']`. Sem  as rotas no meu sistema funciona, mas quando eu coloco as rotas para navegação das páginas, se eu colocar essa dependência no meu controller `['ui.filters']`, da erro.

Por quê acontece isso? Quando se cria rotas no sistema as dependências são criadas em outro local?

Comment: Vc deve injetar essa dependência no seu módulo global. Vc tem um, certo?

Comment: O Meu module global é esse como eu ia passar esse ui.filters ? já tentei de várias formas e nada . angular.module('myApp',['ionic']).config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
 $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
}]).config(function ($ionicConfigProvider) {
 $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.previousTitleText(false).text("").icon("ion-arrow-left-c"); 
});

Answer (score 0):

Repare que você está injetando a biblioteca dentro do nome do seu módulo, faltou separar as duas partes com uma vírgula.

```
 angular.module('myApp', ['ui.filters'])
      .controller("papaRoca", function($scope, Data, $location) {

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

DiogoAugusto nem com isso funcionou alguém me disse que essa biblioteca da conflito com e o injeção do $stateProvider . Não vejo saídas agora alguém conhece alguma forma de filtrar dados para não repetir nome com inoic e Angular js?